# Print function customize

Tags: javascript, html, printing

How i can make every new calculation in new line like this but in print

[image]

Now print look like [image]
Can I remove site url (this is url in live-server)in left bottom?
And date too (top left)?

Code HTML:`<button type="button" id="Print" onclick="printContent('result')" > Print</button>` (result is textarea id).

Code in JS:

```css
function printContent(e) {
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(e).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent  ;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

Comment: If the result is a textarea, read `value` of it  instead of `innerHTML`. You can add/remove header/footer items in browser's printing preferences only, JS can't access those settings.

Comment: How i can get access of this? What lang can edit, If this is posible?

Comment: Start by replacing `\n` line breaks with `<br>` in the string. Or put that into a `<pre>` element which honors `\n` breaks. Or split lines and put each line into a block element

Comment: Let's simplify things and say: it is not possible via a web page to access browser's preferences. You've to remove the header/footer items manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try some like this,

var printcontent = "";

var printcontent2 = "";

for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {

 printcontent = "hi" + x;

console.log(printcontent);

printcontent2 = printcontent2 + printcontent + "<br>";


}
document.body.innerHTML = printcontent2;
window.print();
```